# dynamically add content to tabpages

Tags: c#, winforms

Am trying to dynamically add listboxes and pictures to dynamically created tabpages within a tabcontrol using c#. The form has a button which creates dynamically tabpages to the tabcontrol and also adds inside listboxes and some other content.

The problem is when I hit the button the second time it deletes everything from the previous tab and adds it to the last one.

```
    private void AddNewPr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage tab = new TabPage();
        ListBox list = new ListBox();
        ListBox list2 = new ListBox();
        PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();
        PictureBox pictureBox2 = new PictureBox();
        tab.Name = "tabPage" + n;
        tab.Text = "Property " + n;
        tabControl1.Controls.Add(tab);
        list.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
                "Id",
                "Name"
        });
     //more list properties here///
     //other items here created/////

        tab.Controls.Add(list);
        tab.Controls.Add(list2);
        tab.Controls.Add(pictureBox);

        n++;
    }
```

I also declare an integer incrementor so that all new content have their own name identity.
The other problem I have is I cant access the pictureBox click event handler which is also created dynamically.

Thanks for your help..!!

Comment: Try changing it so you add your `tab` to the `Items` property of the `TabControl`, rather than the `Controls` property.  So it would be: `tabControl1.Items.Add(tab)`.

Comment: Ok I fixed the problem with the content as I had to initialize the list and boxes after the tabs declaration. The only problem now is with the access of the click event handler so that I can add items from dynamic list 1 to 2

Comment: Actually, it looks like you may be using WinForms, not WPF.  Please add a tag for which technology you're using.

Comment: I still don't know how to access list and list2 from the pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){}

Comment: You'll need to create class-level variables to hold references to `list` and `list2` if you want to access them from another method in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the newly created items (`list`, `list2`) from a different method in the class, you'll need to create class-level variables.  For example, expanding your sample above a little:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    //Class-level variables, accessible to all methods in the class
    private ListBox _list;  
    private ListBox _list2;

    private void AddNewPr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage tab = new TabPage();
        _list = new ListBox();
        _list2 = new ListBox();
        PictureBox picBox = new PictureBox();
        picBox.Click = picBox_Click;

        //More stuff here

        //Add the controls        
        tabControl1.Controls.Add(tab);
        tab.Controls.Add(list);
        tab.Controls.Add(list2);
        tab.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
    }

    private void picBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //_list and _list2 are in scope here because they are defined at the class-level
        _list.Items.AddRange(new object()["Id", "Name"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: there's a problem again. When new tab is created "list" in the previous tab cant add anymore items to list2

Comment: Not sure I follow.  If you are adding multiple tabs, and want to keep track of all listboxes on all tabs, you'll need to use a dynamic approach (such as an array) to creating and tracking the listboxes on each tab.  The code above is just a example to demonstrate how you define the `_list` variable at the class scope and use it across different methods in the class.